# reading a csv into a hash

Tags: lua

Hello I am a lua beginner and am trying to loop through a CSV one line at a time. I would like to store each line read from the CSV in a hash table. The current state of the experimental code is as follows:-

```
local fp = assert(io.open ("fields.csv"))
local line=fp:read()
local headers=ParseCSVLine(line,",") 
-- for i,v in ipairs(headers) do print(i,v) end    -- this print outs the CSV header nicely


-- now read the next line from the file and store in a hash
local line=fp:read()
local cols=ParseCSVLine(line,",")
local myfields={}
for i,v in ipairs(headers) do
   -- print( v,cols[i])                            -- this print out the contents nicely
   myfields[v]=cols[i]                             ------ this is where things go bad -----
   end
for i,v in ipairs(myfields) do print(i,v) end      ------ this print nothing!
```

The ParseCSVLine is from the http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCsv. However the issue is the assignment to myfields[v]. Looking at the various docs the syntax of what is allowed within the [] is rather odd and it appears Lua does not allow the use of a symbol here. How do construct my new table in myfields?

Comment: I was not aware I had! I seem to remember I did unclick the 'star' thingy below the question, as this certainly was not my favorite question. At the time your answer was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment to the table looks fine. The problem is when printing the table contents: You used `ipairs` where you should have used `pairs`. `ipairs` is used when iterating over an array (a table where the keys are the sequential numbers 1,2,3,...), and `pairs` can be used over any table to retrieve the key/value pairs, like this:

```
for k,v in pairs(myfields) do print(k,v) end
```